# ring of adeles: ring of integers or valuation ring

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field, adeles

I have read different definitions of the ring of adeles:

> The ring of adeles is defined as the restricted topological product of the completions $K_v$ of a number field $K$ either with respect to the ring of integers of $K_v$ or with respect to the valuation ring of $K_v$.

Do these definitions coincide? If not, what is the "correct" definition?

Comment: If by the valuation ring you mean the set of elements with valuation $\ge0$ then this is the same as the integer ring.

Comment: yes, that is what I mean. How can this be seen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wonder whether the two definitions of integrality in a local field coincide. But an element $x\in K_v$ has a priori infinite degree over $\mathbf Q$, hence cannot be integral over $\mathbf Z$ . Precise definitions are in order : $K$ is a number field, $K_v$ is the completion of $K$ w.r.t. a non archimedean place $v$ . Just as in the answer of @Adam Hughes, define the "valuation ring" $R_v$ = {$x \in K_v : v(x)\ge 0$}, which is a discrete valuation ring, with $K_v$ as its quotient field. If $p$ is the characteristic of the residue field of $v$, then $K_v$ is a finite extension of $\mathbf Q_p$, and your question amounts to showing that $R_v$ coincides with the "ring of integers" $O_v$ of $K_v$, i.e. the integral closure of $\mathbf Z_p$ in  $K_v$.

1) $O_v$ is contained in $R_v$ : let $x \in O_v$ be a root of a monic polynomial $g  \in \mathbf Z_p [X]$, whose coefficients are symmetric functions of the conjugates of $x$ in an algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q_p$. In particular the constant term of $g$ is $\pm N(x)$, where $N$ denotes the norm of $K_v / \mathbf Q_p$. Then the classical formula $v(x) = \frac 1f v_p (N(x))$, where $f$ is the inertia index (see e.g. Serre’s « Local Fields », chap.2, §2) implies $v(x) \ge 0$

2) The converse inclusion can be proved by using the known theorem that $K_v$ is obtained from $\mathbf Q_p$ by taking an unramified extension $N/\mathbf Q_p$ followed by a totally ramified extension $K_v/N$. In each of these extensions, a primitive element is known : $N=\mathbf Q_p(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a root of unity of order prime to $p$, and $K_v=N(\pi)$, where $\pi$ is a uniformizer of $K_v$ (see op. cit., chap.1, §6). It follows that $R_v = \mathbf Z_p[\zeta , \pi]$ is contained in $O_v$ [perhaps there could be a simpler proof ?]

NB : the ring of integers of $K$ itself is the intersection of all the $O_v$ ‘s

*Addendum* : Actually there is a simpler proof of 2). Let $x \in R_v$ and consider its minimal monic polynomial $g  \in \mathbf Q_p [X]$. All the conjugates of $x$ in an algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q_p$ have the same valuation (Serre, chap.2, §2, coroll.3; this is the same principle as behind the norm formula recalled in 1)). The coefficients of $g$ are symmetric functions of these conjugates, hence have valuation $\ge 0$ because $v(ab)=v(a)+v(b)$ and $v(a+b) \ge min(v(a), v(b))$. So in fact $g  \in \mathbf Z_p [X]$ .

Comment: Addendum is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For each (non-Archimedean) completion simply write an arbitrary element $x = \pi^v\cdot u$ for some unit, $u$, and power of the uniformizer, $\pi^v$. Then this is an integer precisely when $v\ge 0$. (recall the restricted product does not talk about the Archimedean completions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why is $x$ an integer if and only if $v \geq 0$?

Comment: @Martin the proof of that will depend on your definition of the local rings. Some use $v\ge 0$ as the definition, others use power series, et cetera. If you provide yours we can suss it out for you.

Comment: my definition of the valuation ring is $o = \lbrace x \in K_v : v(x) \geq 0 \rbrace$

Comment: @Martin well then there you go, recall $v(a\cdot b) = v(a) + v(b)$ and since $v(u)=0$ for all units, $v(x)\ge 0\iff v\ge 0$ when $x=\pi^v\cdot v$.

Comment: but how does this show that $x$ is in the ring of integers (i.e., $x$ satisfies a monic polynomial equation with coefficitents in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @martin that's not what your question asks, it deals with the local integers not the global ones.

Comment: I am a bit confused.. I thought "ring of integers" means in this context the same as in the context of number fields. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Martin oh I think I see you're confusion. You took my question to be asking what your definition of the local rings was to be the valuation ring instead of the local integer ring. For the integer ring, you know it because all the coefficients of the minimal polynomial are limits of integer coefficients, and since $v\ge 0$ on the ordinary integers, this is preserved by the limit since the process is continuous.