The ring of integers of a number field is in valuation ring.
I have a question with a proof.
Let $K$ be a number field and let $v$ be a surjective discrete valuation on $K$. Let $D_v$
the valuation ring of $v$, i.e.
$$D_v=\{x\in K:v(x)≥0\}$$
Let's denote with $O_K$ the ring of integers of $K$. Why do we have the inclusion $O_K\subset D_v$.
I have seen and proof each step of the Hint that is proposed here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2037885/1388299 but there is one step that is not clear to me. Why $\mathbb Z\subset D_v$ (following my notation).
I hope you can help me with this question and if anyone has a better proof I would love to see it. Thank you

If $x\in O_K$ then $x$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, a fortiori integral over $D_v$. Then $x\in D_v$ since $D_v$ is integrally closed.

@XipanXiao Isn't it a ring isomorphic to Z or is there something else when considering a number field?

@Asigan Do you think you can explain to me in more detail why $x\in D_v?$ I can't really visualize it

By definition, the discrete valuation $v$ satisfies the property $v(x + y) \geq \min (v(x), v(y))$. Also, $1 \in D_v$ so we have $v(1 + 1) \geq v(1) \geq 0$. By induction we can see that all positive integers are in $D_v$.
Next, notice $x + 1 = 0$ is a monic polynomial equation with coefficients in $D_v$; hence the solution $-1$ is integral over $D_v$, and because $D_v$ is integrally closed, $-1 \in D_v$. Now apply the same logic from the first paragraph and conclude all of $\mathbb{Z}$ is in $D_v$.
